# Does the D programming language use an incremental garbage collector?

Tags: garbage-collection, d

The [page on the garbage collector](http://dlang.org/garbage.html) doesn't specify whether D uses an incremental garbage collector or a stop-the-world version. It does mention *pausing* a few times, which could be a hint at a stop-the-world garbage collector, but I'm not sure.

If it doesn't use an incremental garbage collector, are there any particular reasons for this? A stop-the-world GC gives a hard time to interactive applications.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Current implementations ([Druntime](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/druntime)) use a **stop-the-world garbage collector**, but the language itself doesn't place many restrictions on the details of an implementation.

There is a concurrent garbage collector for D, [CDGC](http://www.llucax.com.ar/proj/dgc/), for *nix-like OSes (it uses forking).

Incremental GCs are difficult to use in a compiled environment, because of the need of write barriers. VMs can track references, however system languages, which can call `memcpy` and similar functions, cannot.

Comment: Hi there fellow Haunter fan (yes my avatar is inspired by Haunter)! That said, why does an incremental garbage collector need write barriers?

Comment: "Incremental garbage collection" usually implies that application code is allowed to run between the points when heap scanning starts and ends. An object is considered garbage and collected if the GC can't find any references to it... the problem occurs when the GC scans memory block A, then the application code moves the only reference to an object from block B to A, and then the GC scans block B. If the GC doesn't notice that block A was modified after it was scanned, it will never see any references to the object, and discard it.

Comment: This is wrong, it does not necessarily need write barriers in the application code. It needs access to the MMU to track memory writes - on windows we have a memory write watch API. It's not magic and not really difficult.

Comment: I didn't say the write barriers need to be in the application code - they can be implemented by applying the MMU, as you said (using page protection, Get/ResetWriteWatch, what have you). However these do not magically make the problem trivial - we would have already seen an incremental/generational GC for D already otherwise. (Since you're so quick to call me wrong and boast how easy this problem is, where's your incremental/generational GC implementation then? I've actually tried writing one.)